# ChartJS: How to dynamically create data arrays

Tags: javascript, jquery, chart.js

I am working on a Web Application for a client and it has lots of graphs to show data about multiple things.

Currently I am working on a graph that will show skills for each Work item, since work items get added and changed all the time I can't have the chart setup like this...

```
var workName1 = {
    labels : graphWork['New Work']['labels'],
    datasets : [            
        {
            fillColor : "rgba(151,187,205,0.5)",                
            highlightFill : "rgba(151,187,205,0.75)",
            data: graphWork['New Work']['values']
        }
    ]
}

window.onload = function(){       
    var ctx = document.getElementById("canvas").getContext("2d");
    window.myBar = new Chart(ctx).Bar(workName1, {
         // invertXY: true
        // responsive : true,

    });   

 }
```

Doing it this way would be too static and also because I will have a drop down that functions kind of like this,

```
$( "#typeUser" ).change(function() {
    window.myBar.destroy(); 
    chartType = $('#typeUser').val();
    if(chartType == "Random Work"){
        var ctx = document.getElementById("canvas").getContext("2d");
        window.myBar = new Chart(ctx).Bar(randomWork, {
            // responsive : true,
            invertXY: true
        });                
    }else if(chartType == "New Work"){
        var ctx = document.getElementById("canvas").getContext("2d");
        window.myBar = new Chart(ctx).Bar(workName1, {
            // responsive : true,
            invertXY: true
        });  
    }
});
```

Again that is also very static and wouldn't allow for dynamic changes if new work gets added.

**Question:**
What can I do to set this up dynamically. I have thought about doing a $.each on **graphWork** and then some how creating the variable sets that way but then I dunno how I would do the change function or if that is the correct way to go about doing this?

I have setup a JSFiddle that is pulling data and can be used for testing and to see what I am doing. https://jsfiddle.net/L6396hsq/1/

Comment: .update( )

Calling update() on your Chart instance will re-render the chart with any updated values, allowing you to edit the value of multiple existing points, then render those in one animated render loop.

Comment: Can you give me a code example? Not sure how I would implement that.

Comment: How is your data changing?  jquery/ajax?

Comment: Cause people add work and skills all the time so I can't hard code any variables, there is multiple graphs based off what organization they choose, the work name, the job title, etc...

Comment: I didn't ask why, I asked how you are reloading the data into Javascript?

Answer (score 0):

u can with .draw() to new draw the canvaselement if u filled it with new data. 
And with .reflow() u bring the start-motion back ;D

Maybe try this:

```
window.myBar.draw();
window.myBar.reflow();
```

Comment: Can you give me a code example? Not sure how I would implement that.